# Woocommerce: How i can delete a specific product from cart and then empty cart?

Tags: woocommerce

I'm trying, when i remove a specific product with a category "`wifi_plan`" from cart then empty all cart.

how can i do that?

Comment: When, where and why do you want to remove a product with category "wifi_plan" from cart? Do you want to remove it from the CART whenever the product is added to the CART?

Comment: Hello,

The process is the following:

First I can only add a "plan" in the cart.

At checkout, if I delete the "plan", the cart must be automatically deleted